# jquery wait for ajax select dropdown then fill its contents with $.deferred

Tags: jquery

I got 2 selects and I need to fill in the second one after the first one is filled. So the real scenario is like the following:

1) Set `#main_container` dropdown to 2
2) fire `ajax` call and get the contents of child dropdown based on the value of `#main_container` (2 in our case)
3) show child dropdown 2 on the form
3) after all that, set the value of `child dropdown` 2 to 400 so the final result should be Bag Yellow, while it is showing me Bag Green

The problem is that my code is not waiting for the ajax call to finish and display the `child dropdown` 2, it is trying to set `child dropdown` 2 immediately, while I need to set it only after ajax call is done and `child dropdown` 2 is shown on the form. The logic of `main_container` is put in the `onchange` event and it only gets and shows dropdowns. It is NOT setting its values. As far as I know I can use `$.deferred` here but I cannot find out how to wait for `promise` outside `onchange` event.

Any ideas would be welcome. Thank you.

Consider the following simplified code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main_container').val(2);
    $('#main_container').trigger('change');// onchange event is triggered, waiting for child_2 dropdown
    $('#child_2').val(400);//setting child_2 value here (done immediately)
});

$('#main_container').change(function() {

  $('.child').hide();    
  if($(this).val() == 1){
      $('#child_1').show(700); // AJAX call here in real       
    }else if($(this).val() == 2){
      $('#child_2').show(700); // AJAX call here in real
   }else{
      $('#child_3').show(700); // AJAX call here in real
   }
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

div.child {
  display: none
}

select {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option">
  <select name="container" id="main_container" data-parent="true" data-parent_id="10">
  <option value="">--- Select a container---</option>
  <option value="1">Box</option>
  <option value="2">Bag</option>
  <option value="3">Pallet</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="child option" id="child_1" style="display:none;">
  <select name="box color">
  <option value="100">Red</option>
  <option value="200">Blue</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="child option" id="child_2" style="display:none;">
  <select name="bag color">
  <option value="300">Green</option>
  <option value="400">Yellow</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="child option" id="child_3" style="display:none;">
  <select name="pallet color">
  <option value="500">Black</option>
  <option value="600">Yellow</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have an actual ajax call, you can just put the code you want to run afterwards in the `success` function, or in a `then()` function.

Comment: I cannot put the code after `success` function, ajax is only getting dropdown from the server, its actual value is set in other multiple parts of code. Do you know how to use `then()` in `$('document').ready()` section btw. ?

Comment: It's not at all clear where your ajax is used, if it's not used where your code has the comment `// AJAX call here in real`... Please show some code which indicates your real problem is. It doesn't make sense to use `then` unless you have a promise.

Comment: Here I have all `child` dropdowns in html for simplification, in real code I receive them via ajax call which is performed with delay. I put a 700 ms delay here when showing the second dropdown to illustrate the role of that delay. The result actually should be Bag Yellow while it is showing me Bag Green

Answer (score -1):

I have updated the code and found a solution, pls see below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">

        div {
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }

        div.child {
            display: none
        }

        select {
            width: 200px;
        }

    </style>
    <div id="main_div">
        <div class="option">
            <select name="container" id="main_container">
                <option value="">--- Select a container---</option>
                <option value="1">Box</option>
                <option value="2">Bag</option>
                <option value="3">Pallet</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var child_2_div = '<div class="child option" id="child_2" style="display:block;">'+
                                '<select name="bag color" id="child_2_select">'+
                                    '<option value="300">Green</option>'+
                                    '<option value="400">Yellow</option>'+
                                '</select>'+
                            '</div>'; 
        var timerId, dfd;

        function appender(){

            console.log('appender called');

            $('#main_div').append(child_2_div);
            clearInterval(timerId);
            dfd.resolve();
            console.log('logging dfd1');
            console.log(dfd);
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#main_container').val(2);
            $('#main_container').trigger('change');// onchange event is triggered, waiting for child_2 dropdown
            $.when(dfd).then(function(){
                console.log('logging dfd2');
                console.log(dfd);
                $('#child_2_select').val(400);
            }); //setting child_2 value here (done immediately)
        });

        $('#main_container').change(function() {

            $('.child').hide(); 
            $('#child_2').remove();

            if($(this).val() == 2){
                dfd = $.Deferred();
                timerId = setInterval(appender, 1000);

            }else{
                $('#child_3').show(700); // AJAX call here in real
            }
        });



    </script>

</body>
</html>
```